# Passing Boolean from main form

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing variables from main form to input form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433182/passing-variables-from-main-form-to-input-form)
>   [Passing data between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms)

How would i pass the result of a boolean function from a main form? It's basically to check whether the user has authority to edit anything in the program? I basically want to check that boolean on any event that deals with editing. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: So, like a property of the `Form`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433182/passing-variables-from-main-form-to-input-form?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Create a property (or method) on FormOptions, say GetMyResult:

```
 using (FormOptions formOptions = new FormOptions())
{
    formOptions.ShowDialog();

    string result = formOptions.GetMyResult;

    // do what ever with result...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for actually helping sir unlike some of the others

Comment: @jwill22 the reason you've received such an overwhelmingly negative response is that your question has already been answered multiple times. Didn't you try to search on StackOverflow before asking? Were the other answers unhelpful?

Comment: Yes but the answers are not what I wanted.

Comment: You can use only DialogResult property with values DialogResult.OK or any other value

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in many ways,

1. Write a Contructor with bool argument. Pass that argument and decide.
2. Create a bool property which can be accessible from calling method.

Comment: Thanks for actually helping sir unlike some of the others.